# ngx-datatable double initial call on paging

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

this is my implementation using ngx-datatable

**html**

```html
<ngx-datatable
  class="table-base table-base_border clickable-list"
  [rows]="tickets"
  [headerHeight]="30"
  [footerHeight]="50"
  [columns]="columns"
  [columnMode]="'flex'"
  [externalPaging]="true"
  [count]="page.totalElements"
  [offset]="page.pageNumber"
  [limit]="page.size"
  [rowHeight]="40"
  (page)="onPageChange($event)"
  [externalSorting]="true"
  [selectionType]="'single'"
  [messages]="messages | async"
  (select)="onSelect($event)"
  [scrollbarV]="true"
  [scrollbarH]="false"
  [virtualization]="false"
  ></ngx-datatable>
```

**.ts**

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.onPageChange({ offset: 0 });
}

onPageChange(pageInfo: any): void {
  this.page.pageNumber = pageInfo.offset;
  this.gridQuery.page.size = this.page.size;
  this.gridQuery.page.pageNumber = pageInfo.offset + 1;

  this.getData();
}
```

The problem is `getData()` twice, like datatable always call `onPageChange()` after the component is loaded.

How can I prevent double calling of `getData()`?

Comment: Check if data is initialized or use a simple flag?

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is getData() twice, like datatable always call onPageChange() after the component is loaded.

You should not need to call onPageChange in ngOnInit. As you are seeing, the datatable will already call it.